# Hibernate one-to-many , operator doesn't exist ( bytea = integer )

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to use relations one-to-many but I have stuck because of this error:

```
20:17:54,621 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Hibernate: select user0_.user_id as user_id1_1_, user0_.nick as nick2_1_, user0_.password as password3_1_ from users user0_

20:17:54,655 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Hibernate: select userrole0_.users as users3_1_0_, userrole0_.id as id1_0_0_, userrole0_.id as id1_0_1_, userrole0_.role as role2_0_1_, userrole0_.users as users3_0_1_ from user_roles userrole0_ where userrole0_.users=?

20:17:54,657 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-2) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42883
20:17:54,658 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-2) BŁĄD: operator ndoesnt exist: bytea = integer
```

I don't know why I get this exception. I don't use `bytea` operator anywhere. Below, I have provided the source code:

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2051614598479375020L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "nick")
    private String nick;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "users")
    private Set<UserRole> userRole = new HashSet<UserRole>();

    public User(){}


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNick() {
        return nick;
    }

    public void setNick(String nick) {
        this.nick = nick;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


    public Set<UserRole> getUserRole() {
        return userRole;
    }


    public void setUserRole(Set<UserRole> userRole) {
        this.userRole = userRole;
    }

}
```

And UserRole.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_roles")
public class UserRole implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6881696293585198874L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    private User users;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    public User getUser() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUser(User users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }   
}
```

I assume that this is an easy problem but I don't know how solve it.

Comment: could it be that your key column for this relation has different data types on both tables? Please check in the db directly for the datatype of this column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `UserRole` uses field-access, because the @Id is placed on a field. The **user** `@ManyToOne` association is placed on a property instead. You need to move it to the field level too:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private User user;
```

This was causing your issue. When Hibernate was loading the UserRole, the User table FK was loaded from the `user` field which was not annotated, so a null was used instead.

I also changed the fetch attribute to LAZY since EAGER fetching is [a bad idea](https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/).

Another minor change is related to the `User` identifier type. It should use `Integer` rather than `int`:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Integer id;
```

Using a wrapper can allow you to differentiate between a transient entity and an attached/detached one.